# How to upload photo taken on phone through devapp on firebase storage in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4, firebase-storage, ionic-devapp

I am trying to **upload a photo taken through my phone's camera** (With Ionic 4 Native `Camera Plugin` through **DevApp**) and upload it to `Firebase Storage`. Now I am able to take the photo, but when I upload it, the console does not throw any errors and just does not do anything. In the end, the photo is not uploaded to the firebase storage.

Here are my codes:

.html:

```
<ion-button (click)="takePicture()"></ion-button>
```

.ts:

```
  takePicture(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
     }

     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
       var storage = firebase.storage().ref();
       var photoRef = storage.child('Manager Images'); 
       console.log(photoRef); <-- This reference is correct

       let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
       console.log(base64Image); <-- Returns "data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.devapp/cache/1577622281686.jpg"

       // Base64 formatted string
       var message = imageData;
       photoRef.putString(message , 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' }).then((savedPicture) => {
       console.log(savedPicture.downloadURL);
});


   }, (err) => {
    // Handle error
   });
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong with the .putString method? I referred to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files for the guidelines but I still can't get this to work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change destination type to `this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` to get base64 and then put it into firebase storage.

```
  takePicture(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    ...
```

PS. be sure if `let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;` is necessarily or if `imageData` already has coded type in base64 format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked! I left the base64Image variable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and it should work.

```
var message = base64Image;
```

imageData is not 'base64'

Or Upload as File ,Use the file as it is.

```
var file = imageData
photoRef.put(file).then(snapshot => {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!')
});
```

Comment: By the way, when I did the console.log for the 'message' variable, this is what I got:

"data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.devapp/cache/1577622281686.jpg"

I have a feeling it's because of the link after the base64,file:///...

Comment: Try the Above. did you try as file before using Put ?

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. The outcome is the same as before.